# Network-wide feature request to support TeX in tables

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Many of us here frequently use MathJax, whether for this site or another site on the SE Network.

Recently SE added support for tables, but ignored the needs of the TeX community, who wish to be able to type TeX symbols/formulas/etc. as well.

#### [This is the feature request on Meta.SE, to support MathJax in tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357525/391772).

Here's some network-wide examples where such support would be needed (please add anymore if you're aware of any!):

- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1720/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1247/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3857/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/361/5

Comment: I tried to use the table feature here and it didn't work either. I'd like to get the tables working on space stack exchange.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Tables work here. It's just that MathJax and other markup (such as blockquotes) don't work in tables.

Comment: Didn't work when I tried it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble When did you try? They just enabled it this week. Also, the syntax is very particular.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sure I've used MathJax to do tables...

Comment: @JCRM As in the examples in my question?

Comment: @JCRM This is about using MathJax in markup tables, not making tables in MathJax.

Comment: Yes, @called2voyage, I'm quite aware. It just amused me there were problems with using MathJax in tables, when in the past people have abused MathJax to implement tables. However, marginally more seriously, it should follow that one can use MathJax in MathJax tables

Comment: @JCRM Ok, wasn't sure if that was sarcasm or genuine confusion.

Comment: Why do you need to have such markup tables? Also Latex has tables, afaik they work with MathJax!